# Export Response based on Name from Chrome Network tab in DevTools

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

Is it possible somehow export Response information from Network tab from Chrome Dev Tools with python?
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by right-clicking on the request to be exported and there will be
"Save all as HAR with content",Or directly copy the string that returns the result

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this saving process via python code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python then you can get the same information that you see in the Response tab, using the requests library,

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
>>> print response.content
```